# CakePHP query - complex AND/OR conditions

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm trying to get my head around the complex find conditions of CakePHP and have read [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) but am struggling with this one query.

```
SELECT field1,
       field2
WHERE id = 123456
  AND ((holding_date = Last_day(holding_date)
        AND Month(holding_date) IN(3, 6, 9, 12))
       OR (holding_date = '2013-09-15'))
```

To produce the above conditions what would my `conditions` array look like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### CakePHP conditions and sql expressions

While the conditions in the question are not that complex, they touch on a few points which mean they can be tricky to define correctly. Some of the things to know when defining cakephp conditions:

- Conditions are defined as an array of key => value pairs, as such the same key cannot be defined twice on the same level
- an array element which has a numeric key is interpreted as an sql expression
- The default join mode is "AND" - it's not necessary to specify `"AND" => ...` in conditions
- An OR conditions must have more than one elements. There's no error if it has only one but otherwise: OR what?

Bearing in mind the above notes, the conditions in the question can be expressed as:

```
$foo->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'field1',
        'field2'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => 123456,
        'OR' => array(
            array(
                'holding_date = LAST_DAY(holding_date)',
                'MONTH(holding_date)' => array(3,6,9,12)
            ),
            'holding_date' => '2013-09-15'
        )
    )
));
```

Which results in:

```
WHERE 
    `id` = 123456
    AND 
    (
        (
            (holding_date = LAST_DAY(holding_date))  
            AND
            (MONTH(holding_date) IN (3, 6, 9, 12)))
        )
        OR 
        (`holding_date` = '2013-09-15')
    )
```

Note: whitespace is quite important =) I misread the question originally solely because of the inconsistent whitespace in the question's sql.

Comment: +1 good answer, but I would advise placing `OR` rules in their own arrays. PHP will not warn if keys are duplicated and if you have two rules on `hold_date` only the last will be used.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini unnecessary nesting makes things hard to read though - so it's IMO only a good idea to do that when it's required, or conditions are being built itteratively (The same can be said for any array key, `OR` isn't a special case). If `holding_date` were in two `OR` comparisons it'd be more appropriate to use `IN` (i.e. `'holding_date' => array('first', 'second')`).

Comment: Yes, good answer. While I did get there on my own your exclusion of the unnecessary "AND"s makes it more concise. Apologies about the whitespace - wasn't quite sure how to apply it to SQL

Answer (score 3):

OK I have solved it:

```
$findParams['conditions'] = array(
            'Account.client_id' => '12345',
            'AND' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'Holding.holding_date' => '2013-09-15',
                    'AND' => array(
                        'Holding.holding_date = LAST_DAY(Holding.holding_date)',
                        'MONTH(Holding.holding_date)' => array(3,6,9,12)
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$params['conditions'] = array(
    '`id`' =>  123456,
    'AND' => array(
        '`holding_date`' => 'LAST_DAY(`holding_date`)',
        'AND' => array(
            'MONTH(holding_date)' => array(3, 6, 9, 12),
            'OR' => array(`holding_date` => '2013-09-15')
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I can tell without trying that this isn't right; you have grouped one of the 1st date conditions in the same array as the `OR` condition. From what I can tell this will always require the first condition to be satisfied when this isn't what I want.

Comment: I english my condition is "record must fall on the last day of the quarter [the first 2 conditions] OR be on a date that I specify [the last condition]"